# VBA =RANDBETWEEN

Tags: excel, random, vba

I hope you can help me figure out what I am unable to do myself. I work as an Auditor with large data sets and want to make taking samples easier for myself and everyone I work with.

I am trying to set up a random number generator using =RANDBETWEEN

What I would like to do is specify a field in which I type the range i.e. (1,20) and then for =RANDBETWEEN to pick that value up and generate numbers, but WITHOUT repeating any.

I bet there is a way, I just haven't considered it most likely and have a blonde moment.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what was found [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/277386/non-identical-random-numbers)

For a formula answer you will need two columns of formulas and an individual cell for the starting number and another cell for the ending number.

I used E1 for the starting number and F1 for the ending number.

Then in A1 I put the following:

```
=IF(ROW()<=$F$1-$E$1+1,RAND(),"")
```

And in C1 I put:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A:$A,ROW(1:1)),$A:$A,0)+$E$1-1,"")
```

Then I copied both A1 and C1 down enough rows to cover the largest possible range I would want.

[image]

As you can see I wanted random numbers between 5 and 20.  In column C I got 16 numbers from 5 to 20 in random order.

If I change the range from 6 to 15 it changes:

[image]

One note:  The Aggregate Function was introduced in Excel 2010.  So this will not work for earlier editions.

If you are using an earlier edition use this in C1:

```
=IF(A1<>"",RANK(A1,A:A)+$E$1-1,"")
```

And copy down.

---

As for a vba version:

```
Sub RndmUnquArr()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mnm&, mxm&
Dim oArr() As Variant
Dim i&, j&, x&, temp&

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    mnm = .Range("E1") 'change as desired
    mxm = .Range("F1") 'change as desired

    ReDim tArr(0 To (mxm - mnm)) As Variant
    ReDim oArr(mnm To mxm) As Variant

    'Load array with integers from mnm to mxm
    For i = mnm To mxm
        oArr(i) = i
    Next i

    'Randomly suffle arr
    x = UBound(oArr)
    For j = LBound(oArr) To UBound(oArr)

        i = Int((x - mnm + 1) * Rnd + mnm)
        temp = oArr(i)
        oArr(i) = oArr(x)
        oArr(x) = temp

        x = x - 1
    Next j

    .Range("A1").Resize(mxm - mnm + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(oArr)
    ws.Calculate
End With

End Sub
```

Again the lower extant is in E1 and the upper is in F1

Comment: Good answer - note that there is another VBA solution, which would generally involve something like "Do While [x has no duplicates]", which continues to assign a random number to incremental members of an array, until the random number is not a duplicate. Such a method would possibly be 'cleaner' / 'easier to understand & code', but for large arrays should be avoided. Scott's method here [or something like it] would be preferred.

Comment: Also - in terms of understanding Scott's method, consider it to be 2 stages: First, create a deck of x cards, and give each card a unique value [ie: the 20 rows in the first example]. Then, randomize the *order* of those cards, using the Rand() function, and sort from highest to lowest. Finally, pick the top y results, for the number of unique numbers you need from your list. This 2 step solution may seem more complex than 1 step of 'Randomize and check for duplicates', but it becomes increasingly more efficient as your array grows larger.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, I actually started with that one, but the second time I ran it, it went into a loop stall for 2 minutes trying to fill the last number in the array.  It just could not quite randomly put in that last unique number.

Comment: I don't have a CS background, but I've read the problem elsewhere as 'the running time of such a program is theoretically infinite because as it iterates there is never a guarantee it falls on the correct number'. With large arrays, this theoretical infinity quickly becomes an actual 'long time', at minimum.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon my background is Construction Management with a masters in Business.  I just throw things at the wall till something sticks.

Comment: @Thecatsloose Glad to help.